# jquery, radio buttons, validation, and indexes problem

Tags: jquery-validate, radio-button

I have a set of radio buttons with the name="rb_Select".

I added a simple radio button validation to make sure that at lease 1 radio button was selected, but i see now that i have my syntax is my javascript function written incorrectly.

Basically, what i am checking for is true / false values in a if else statement. however, I realized that if no radio button is selected then i get multiple false values. Say i have 8 radio buttons, i'm getting 8 alerts windows while i am debugging.

IF i select 1 radio button, then i get one true and 7 false. But that's not what i want.

What i want is 1 true and no false.  I'm not sure what the syntax should be.  I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Here is the submit function:

```
var $ = jQuery;

$("#pError").hide();
$("#LocInfo").hide();

$(".submit-button").click(function() {

    var rb = document.getElementsByName('rb_Select');

    for (var i = 0; i < rb.length; i++)
    {
        if (rb[i].checked == true)
        {

        alert('Value=' + rb[i].value + 'TRUE');
        var myURL = rb[i].value;
        window.open(myURL);


        } else {

        alert('Value=' + rb[i].value + 'False');

        $("#pError").fadeIn();
        var fade_out = function() { $("#pError").fadeOut(); }
            setTimeout(fade_out, 3000);
        };

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the selector `input[type='radio'][name='rb_Select']:checked` with the **length** method to see if the radio was selected.

Try this:

```
  var $ = jQuery;

    $("#pError").hide();
    $("#LocInfo").hide();

    $(".submit-button").click(function() {

        var radios = $("input[type='radio'][name='rb_Select']:checked");
        if(radios.length > 0){
            alert('Value=' + radios.val() + 'TRUE');
            window.open(radios.val());
        }       else{

            alert('Value=' + radios.val()+ 'False');

            $("#pError").fadeIn();
            var fade_out = function() { $("#pError").fadeOut(); }
                setTimeout(fade_out, 3000);
            };
        }
    });
```

Comment: everything is great in your script except one line: 

if(radios.length() > 0){

should be:

if(radios.length > 0 ) {

Having the () makes javascript think its a function. :)

Thanks for your help!